# Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0 terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I've read all of the related posts regarding this and am still having an error:

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of
>   rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be
>   equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
>   update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
>   that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Here are the details:

i use code to open piano table when open cell it gives sub cells each row has different number of cells it was work well but i need to modify some thing that when i click on row it open then if i click on another row i need it to open the second and close the first opened row 
this is my code 
rootView.m

```
#pragma -mark TableViewDelegate
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    GCRetractableSectionController* sectionController = [self.retractableControllers objectAtIndex:section];
    //    NSLog(@"sectionController.numberOfRow %d",sectionController.numberOfRow );
    return sectionController.numberOfRow;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    GCRetractableSectionController* sectionController = [self.retractableControllers objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    return [sectionController cellForRow:indexPath.row];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"index path section %d indexrow %d",indexPath.section  ,indexPath.row);

    GCRetractableSectionController* sectionController = [self.retractableControllers objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];


  //  vc.open = !vc.open;


//    return [sectionController didSelectCellAtRow:indexPath.row];



    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        [myCustomView setHidden:YES];
           NSLog(@"index path 11111 111111 1111111 indexrow %d",indexPath.row);



    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    }

    return [sectionController didSelectCellAtRow:indexPath.row];




}
```

// GCRetractableSectionController.m

```
   #import "GCRetractableSectionController.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface GCRetractableSectionController ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *viewController;

- (void) setAccessoryViewOnCell:(UITableViewCell*) cell;

@end

@implementation GCRetractableSectionController

@synthesize useOnlyWhiteImages, titleTextColor, titleAlternativeTextColor;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize open, rowAnimation;
@synthesize backUp;
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialisation

- (id) initWithViewController:(UIViewController*) givenViewController {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        if (![givenViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView)]) {
            //The view controller MUST have a tableView proprety
            [NSException raise:@"Wrong view controller" 
                        format:@"The passed view controller to GCRetractableSectionController must respond to the tableView proprety"];
        }
        self.viewController = givenViewController;
    //  self.open = NO;
        self.useOnlyWhiteImages = NO;
        self.rowAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;

    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Getters

- (UITableView*) tableView {
    return [self.viewController performSelector:@selector(tableView)];
}

- (NSUInteger) numberOfRow {
    NSLog(@"the count %d",self.contentNumberOfRow);

    return (self.open) ? self.contentNumberOfRow + 1 : 1;
}

- (NSUInteger) contentNumberOfRow {
    return 0;
}

- (NSString*) title {
    return NSLocalizedString(@"No title",);
}

- (NSString*) titleContentForRow:(NSUInteger) row {
    return NSLocalizedString(@"No title",);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Cells

- (UITableViewCell *) cellForRow:(NSUInteger)row {
    UITableViewCell* cell = nil;

    if (row == 0) cell = [self titleCell];
    else cell = [self contentCellForRow:row - 1];

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) titleCell {
    NSString* titleCellIdentifier = [NSStringFromClass([self class]) stringByAppendingString:@"title"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:titleCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:titleCellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = self.title;
    if (self.contentNumberOfRow != 0) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%i items",), self.contentNumberOfRow];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        [self setAccessoryViewOnCell:cell];
    }
    else {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"No item",);
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) contentCellForRow:(NSUInteger)row {
    NSString* contentCellIdentifier = [NSStringFromClass([self class]) stringByAppendingString:@"content"];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:contentCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:contentCellIdentifier] ;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self titleContentForRow:row];

    return cell;
}

- (void) setAccessoryViewOnCell:(UITableViewCell*) cell {
    NSString* path = nil;
    if (self.open) {
        path = @"UpAccessory";
        if (self.titleAlternativeTextColor == nil) cell.textLabel.textColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.191 green:0.264 blue:0.446 alpha:1.000];
        else cell.textLabel.textColor = self.titleAlternativeTextColor;
    }   
    else {
        path = @"DownAccessory";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = (self.titleTextColor == nil ? [UIColor blackColor] : self.titleTextColor);
    }

    UIImage* accessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:path];
    UIImage* whiteAccessoryImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[[path stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingString:@"White"]];

    UIImageView* imageView;
    if (cell.accessoryView != nil) {
        imageView = (UIImageView*) cell.accessoryView;
        imageView.image = (self.useOnlyWhiteImages ? whiteAccessoryImage : accessoryImage);
        imageView.highlightedImage = whiteAccessoryImage;
    }
    else {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:(self.useOnlyWhiteImages ? whiteAccessoryImage : accessoryImage)];
        imageView.highlightedImage = whiteAccessoryImage;
        cell.accessoryView = imageView;
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Select Cell

- (void) didSelectCellAtRow:(NSUInteger)row {
    if (row == 0) {
           [self didSelectTitleCell];
    }
    else [self didSelectContentCellAtRow:row - 1];
}

- (void) didSelectTitleCell {


    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *myDecodedObject  = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"tableViewDataPrevious"];
    NSMutableArray *decodedArray =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myDecodedObject];
    NSLog(@"the back Up Count %d",[decodedArray count]);
    if ([decodedArray count]!=0){

        NSLog(@"Back Up Array ");
        NSLog(@"am here herer hererer hererer %@ " , decodedArray);



        // it quit here
       [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:decodedArray withRowAnimation:self.rowAnimation];
        //


        [self.tableView reloadData];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];

//        NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
//        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
        NSLog(@"am here herer hererer hererer");

    }

    NSLog(@"didSelectedTitleCell");
    self.open = !self.open;
    NSLog(@"1");
    if (self.contentNumberOfRow != 0) [self setAccessoryViewOnCell:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]];

    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    NSUInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSUInteger contentCount = self.contentNumberOfRow;

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSMutableArray* rowToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < contentCount + 1; i++) {
        NSIndexPath* indexPathToInsert = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section];
        [rowToInsert addObject:indexPathToInsert];
    }

    if (self.open) {


        NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         NSData *myDecodedObject  = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"tableViewDataPrevious"];
        NSMutableArray *decodedArray =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myDecodedObject];

        NSLog(@"the back Up Count %d",[decodedArray count]);

        if ([decodedArray count]!=0){

            NSLog(@"Back Up Array ");
         [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:decodedArray withRowAnimation:self.rowAnimation];


             //[self.tableView endUpdates];

            NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];


        }
             [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:rowToInsert withRowAnimation:self.rowAnimation];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];



         backUp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [backUp addObjectsFromArray:rowToInsert];
         NSLog(@"the back Up Count %@", backUp );
        NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:backUp];

        [userDefaults setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:@"tableViewDataPrevious"];
        ;
        [userDefaults synchronize];




    }
    else {
         [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:rowToInsert withRowAnimation:self.rowAnimation];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
}


    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    if (self.open) [self.tableView scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void) didSelectContentCellAtRow:(NSUInteger)row {

}

@end
```

and the output is

```
2014-10-09 13:10:13.747 Brnlysta2[10199:90b] the back Up Count (
        "<NSIndexPath: 0x8e8fb80> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}",
        "<NSIndexPath: 0x8e87900> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}",
        "<NSIndexPath: 0x8e871c0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}",
        "<NSIndexPath: 0x8e908e0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}"
    )
    2014-10-09 13:10:14.717 Brnlysta2[10199:90b] index path section 1 indexrow 0
    2014-10-09 13:10:14.718 Brnlysta2[10199:90b] the back Up Count 4
    2014-10-09 13:10:14.718 Brnlysta2[10199:90b] Back Up Array 
    2014-10-09 13:10:14.719 Brnlysta2[10199:90b] am here herer hererer hererer (
        "<NSIndexPath: 0x8b3bb60> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}",
        "<NSIndexPath: 0x8b8e5c0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}",
        "<NSIndexPath: 0x8b75f60> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}",
        "<NSIndexPath: 0x8b7b960> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}"
    ) 
    2014-10-09 13:10:14.719 Brnlysta2[10199:90b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:1368
    2014-10-09 13:10:14.722 Brnlysta2[10199:90b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 4 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x017fe1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0157d8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x017fe048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
        3   Foundation                          0x0115d4de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
        4   UIKit                               0x00315f63 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 13402
        5   UIKit                               0x00326590 -[UITableView _updateRowsAtIndexPaths:updateAction:withRowAnimation:] + 337
        6   UIKit                               0x0032660b -[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] + 55
        7   Brnlysta2                           0x0000368e -[GCRetractableSectionController didSelectTitleCell] + 382
        8   Brnlysta2                           0x000034d7 -[GCRetractableSectionController didSelectCellAtRow:] + 71
        9   Brnlysta2                           0x00008f13 -[RootViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 531
        10  UIKit                               0x003279a1 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1513
        11  UIKit                               0x00327b14 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 279
        12  UIKit                               0x0032c10e __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
        13  UIKit                               0x0025b0aa ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
        14  UIKit                               0x0025b055 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
        15  UIKit                               0x0025ae76 _afterCACommitHandler + 532
        16  CoreFoundation                      0x017c636e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
        17  CoreFoundation                      0x017c62bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
        18  CoreFoundation                      0x017a4254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
        19  CoreFoundation                      0x017a39d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
        20  CoreFoundation                      0x017a37eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        21  GraphicsServices                    0x037a25ee GSEventRunModal + 192
        22  GraphicsServices                    0x037a242b GSEventRun + 104
        23  UIKit                               0x0023df9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
        24  Brnlysta2                           0x0000669d main + 141
        25  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e43725 start + 0
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something which edits/updates UITableView, it check some dataSource methods if data integrity is still exists or not. You have a problem with that. On your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` or `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:` method, there is a miscalculation. Before calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths, so also need to update the necessary properties which are used to calculate the section/row counts.

By the way, there is no meaning using reloadData after deleteRowsAtIndexPaths. It might interfere with your deletion animation.

Comment: We cannot tell without seeing numberOfSectionsInTableView and tableView: numberOfRowsInSection: methods.

Comment: ok , its to long , i use multiple objects for row and each controller return the number of rows os its row section

Comment: but lets say i have 4 section , i have 4 roes , 2 have 6 rows , 3 have 6 rows , 4 is empty

Comment: then before calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths, update those object so they return correct number of rows after deletion.

Comment: well, without seeing source code it's really hard to understand. the main problem i see is your tableview data is not well structured.

Comment: yours have any idea ??

Comment: you should update GCRetractableSectionController's so they return correct numberOfRow etc. How to do that is beyond anyone's help here, i guess.

Comment: ok , i put all of the code of GCRetractableSectionController can yours add any thing ??

Comment: @DenizAdalar thanks for your answer. In my case, in my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath change the background color depending if it's an odd or even cell number. When I delete the row with an animation I have two consecutive cells with the same bg color. If I use .reloadDate() I lose the animation. How can I do? Thanks